# google heatmaps for asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, google-maps

I am trying to create a google heatmap in my asp.net application but I can't find any good links?

Does anyone know any good links how to implement this for asp.net? Or maybe if something else is available where can I find this?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean google sitemap?  There's a good Codeproject article here: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/GoogleSiteMapProvider.aspx